# Grammar to recognize unlimited '{' expr '}' next to each-other

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I am writing a C# application using [ANTLR4](http://www.antlr.org/) to recognize the following [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)'ish style:

> {a}{x}+{b}{y}+{c}

My current grammar always takes the last instance of **'{' expr '}'** then ignores beginning of string. Here are some output results from current grammar (described below):

- *Input:* {a}  ***Output:*** a **[Pass]**
- *Input:* {a}+{x} ***Output:*** a + x **[Pass]**
- *Input:* {a}{x} ***Output:*** x **[Fail]** *Desired:* ax
- *Input:* {a}{x}+{b} ***Output:*** x + b **[Fail]** *Desired:* ax + b
- *Input:* {a}{x}+{b}{y} ***Output:*** y **[Fail]** *Desired:* ax + by
- *Input:* {a}{x}+{b}{y}+{c} ***Output:*** y + c **[Fail]** *Desired:* ax + by + c
- *Input:* {a}{x}+{b}{y}+{c}{d} ***Output:*** d  **[Fail]** *Desired:* ax + by + cd

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Grammar MyGra.g4 file:**

```
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */
prog: expr+ ;

expr : '{' expr '}'                 # CB_Expr
     | expr op=('+'|'-') expr       # AddSub
     | '{' ID '}'                   # CB_ID
     | ID                           # ID
     ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */
ID: ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')+;
ADD : '+';
SUB : '-';
WS:   (' ' | '\r' | '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

**MyGraVisitor.CS file:**

```
 public override string VisitID(MyGraParser.IDContext context)
 {
      return context.ID().GetText();
 }

 public override string VisitAddSub(MyGraParser.AddSubContext context)
 {
     if (context.op.Type == MyGraParser.ADD)
     {
         return Visit(context.expr(0)) + " + " + Visit(context.expr(1));
     }
     else
     {
         return Visit(context.expr(0)) + " - " + Visit(context.expr(1));
     }
 }

 public override string VisitCB_Expr(MyGraParser.CB_ExprContext context)
 {
     return Visit(context.expr());
 }

 public override string VisitCB_ID(MyGraParser.CB_IDContext context)
 {
     return context.ID().GetText();
 }
```

### Update #1:

It was suggested to include a grammar rule for

```
'{' expr '}{' expr '}'
```

however, what if I have **{a}{b}{c}{d}+{e}{f}{g}**, I thought grammar was supposed to account for recursive versions of "itself" via parse trees... so what if I have 1000 {expr}'s next to each-other? How many rules do I need then? I think the suggestion is valid, except I am not sure how to account for unlimited amounts of {expr} next to each-other?

Another question I have is: How can I re-use the rule **CB_Expr**?

### Update #2:

I added the rule:

```
| expr CB_Expr                  # CB_Expr2
```

with visitor:

```
public override string VisitCB_Expr2(MyGra.CB_Expr2Context context)
{
    return Visit(context.expr()) + Visit(context.CB_Expr());
}
```

That did not help, I still get the same output for all cases (described above).

Comment: what does c# has to do with it

Comment: Where is your rule to allow {expr}{expr}? How is {a}{b} supposed to be interpreted? I see that missing from your grammar and the failures I'm seeing appear to be related.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick87, I have updated question

Comment: Please narrow down your question to something specific.  The question has a "do my work for me" air to it...

Comment: `CB_ID` is superflusouly ambiguous. The parse for `{x}` has two possible trees: `CB_Expr (ID)` or `CB_ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar is ambigous. For example: The input {x} can have two different parse trees (as Mephy said):

> (CB_Expr { (expr (ID x)) })

and

> (DB_ID {x})

Removing the CB_ID would fix this without actually doing anything negative.

For you actual problem, this should do the trick for expr:

```
expr : left=id_expr op=('+' |'-') right=expr #AddSub
     | id_expr                               #ID_Expr
     ;

id_expr :
     | '{' ID '}' id_expr                    #ID_Ex
     | '{' ID '}'                            #ID
     ;
```

I have not tested this though, and I have not written you any visitors, but the grammar should work.

The id_expr rule works recursively, so you should be able to put as many {ID} after each other as you want - at least one though, the way the grammar is right now.